# How do I force close a process run as admin, when program sending command is not admin?

Tags: java, windows, command-line, admin, command-prompt

For testing and security purposes, I am trying to make a Java program that force closes certain processes. I am testing it with the "taskmgr.exe" process and the "cmd.exe" process.

It works fine with taskmgr.exe no matter what, but it only works on cmd.exe if command prompt is NOT run as admin. I am using `taskkill /F` to close these in my code:

```
String line;
    String pidInfo = "";
    while (true) {
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\"
                            + "tasklist.exe");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        try {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                pidInfo += line;
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (pidInfo.contains("taskmgr.exe")) {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                rt.exec("taskkill /F /T /IM taskmgr.exe");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(pidInfo.contains("cmd.exe")) {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                rt.exec("taskkill /F /T /IM cmd.exe");
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This all works just fine. But how would I modify the code so that it can also force Admin Command Prompt to quit? For my purposes, I can't be running the Java program as Admin. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, you are asking whether a non-admin process can kill an admin process.

That's not possible.

So, no amount of changes in your code can accomplish it.

(At least not without some m4d h4x0r ski11z, which we are not allowed to talk about here.)

Comment: Actually, you _are_ [very much allowed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262749/510036) to talk about hacks here. One of the few good reasons I still use SO. :)

Comment: That's what I thought. Oh well, then. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Qix yes, of course. I was joking.  (Cool name, by the way; I used to play that arcade game.)

Comment: @Qix Well, if we're allowed to talk about it, then I may as well state my program: it simply says "Can you close the program?" With a close button. The button just opens another window of that first window. Same with the Windows close button. And it closes task manager to close so that people can't close it, but mine isn't a virus since it does no harm and you *can* close it. I love computers :)